# Area2D only detecting body_exited once

Tags: 2d, collision-detection, godot, events, gdscript

I am new to game development, I am practicing by creating a pong game.

I currently have an `Area2D` set up with a signal listening for `body_exited` (the body in question being the ball), it detects the ball exiting and then resets the ball in the middle of the screen. However, it only does this once. If the ball leaves the `Area2D` again, it doesn't fire and reset.

[image: Pong field]

[image: Screenshot of scene hierarchy]

```
extends Node2D

func _on_area_2d_body_exited(body):
    $Ball.StaticBody2D.position = Vector2(550, 325)
```

Comment: I don't know if this would help, but you could try sending the detected body to the position, so if the ball leaves, it would send it back. So what I mean is do this:

`body.position = Vector2(550,325)`

I don't know if this is a smarter solution (You could also use groups so you only move the ball).

Answer (score 3):

The ball being an static body is odd... I suspect the `Area2D` is not detecting the static body at all, see the issue: [Area2D does not detect moving StaticBody2D](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/81883).

I would like to encourage to change the ball to be either a `CharacterBody2D` (`KinematicBody2D` in Godot 3.x) or a `RigidBody2D`. Your code should be easier to adapt to `CharacterBody2D`/`KinematicBody2D` as you can continue to move it by the same means.

The `RigidBody2D` might save you the code for the ball bouncing (you might want to remove gravity), but you need trickery to teleport it...

Teleporting a `RigidBody2D`:

```
PhysicsServer2D.body_set_state(
    rigid_body_2d.get_rid(),
    PhysicsServer2D.BODY_STATE_TRANSFORM,
    Transform2D.IDENTITY.translated(Vector2(1.0, 2.0))
)
```

*Note: If you are using Godot 3, you would use `Physics2DServer` instead of `PhysicsServer2D`.*

---

*Consider also using areas around the playing field, either using big `RectangleShape2D` or `WorldBoundaryShape2D` (which is intended for this use case).*

---

For advice on which physics body to use consider: [When should I use a KinematicBody or a RigidBody for 2D platformer characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75617655/402022)